# Declaración e inicialización de una variable

Tags: programación-funcional, dart

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre?

```
var currentLocation = LocationData;
var currentLocation = LocationData();
```

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje?

Comment: El lenguaje en el que estoy trabajando es dart.

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte de los docs de Dart responde a tu duda: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage

La transcribo en castellano a continuación:

> Cuando llamas un método en un objeto sin paréntesis, Dart te ofrece un
>   "tear-off" (un cierre que toma los mismos parámetros que el métdo y lo
>   invoca cuando lo llama.
>
> Si tienes una función que invoca un método con los mismos argumentos
>   que se le pasan, no necesitas ajustar manualmente la llamada en una
>   lambda.
>
> ```
> nombres.forEach(print);
> nombres.forEach((nombre) {
>   print(nombre);
> });
> ```